# Calculating a rotation volume rotating around $y=1$.

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve the following:

Calculate the volume of the rotation when $y=1-x^2, 0≤x≤1$, and the x-axis, rotates around the line $y=1$.

I've tried to find the integral but is unsure if my work is correct or if I'm missing something when calculating the area or radius which would lead to an incorrect integral.

[image]

Comment: Since the rotated object has a void in the middle, I would suggest integrating the top part (between $y=1-x^2$ and $y=1$) instead of the bottom part (between $y=0$ and $y=1-x^2$). After you have the volume of that object, you can subtract it from the volume of the cylinder.

Comment: Actually now I see that, what you have done here is the volume of the upper part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is correct but you have found volume of the unshaded region between $x = 0$ and $x = 1$, rotated around $y = 1$. You need to subtract the result $\pi/5$ from $\pi$ which is the volume of the cylinder of radius $1$ between $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. That would give you the volume of the shaded region rotated around $y = 1$.

Using washer method:

As the region is between the parabola and x-axis, the area of cross section is

$A = \pi \cdot 1^2 - \pi (x^2)^2 = \pi (1-x^4)$

So the integral to find volume should be,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^1 \pi (1-x^4) ~ dx = \frac{4 \pi}{5}$

Using cylindrical shell method:

Take a cylindrical shell at distance $y$ above x-axis so at a distance of $(1-y)$ from line $y = 1$. The width of the cylindrical shell between $x = 0$ and the parabola is $ \sqrt{1-y}$.

So the integral to find volume is,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^1 2 \pi (1-y) \sqrt{1-y} ~ dy  = \frac{4 \pi}{5}$

Comment: So using the washer method it would be as if y=1 is the new x-axis? Or is that an incorrect way of thinking?

Comment: That may not be the correct way of thinking. Rather think this way - if we take a washer with inner radius of $r_1$ (the radius of the hole) and outer radius of $r_2$, what is the area of the washer? It is $\pi (r_2^2 - r_1^2)$, right. Same way in this case, distance from $y =1 $ to parabola $y = 1 - x^2$ is the inner radius (the hole) and $y = 1$ to $y = 0$ is the outer radius ($1$).

Comment: Thank you, I think I have a better understanding now. So to calculate the integral from the beginning would be simply (1^2 - (1+x^2)^2 - 1^2)?

Comment: It is $ \pi (1^2 - (1 - (1 - x^2))^2) = \pi (1 - x^4)$ as in my answer. The distance from $y = 1$ to parabola $y = 1 - x^2$ is $1 - (1 - x^2) = x^2$

Comment: I was just a bit confused to where the 1 came from but know I totally understand. Once again thank you! :)

Comment: You are welcome. One quick advice - please learn mathjax through a basic tutorial on the site and start using it to type your questions. Images cannot be searched. Questions not using mathjax are not encouraged on the site.